# Avoiding writing full database name and path in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

So i imported the adventure works database in console project in visual studio 2012.

Now the problem is that whenever i have to write a query i have to write the whole path to get access to the table in database and it become something like.

```
SELECT * FROM [C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\SQL_PRACTICE\SQL_PRACTICE\ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA.MDF].HumanResources.Employee;
```

I mean it become really long. Anyway i can avoid writing the full path in a query.

Comment: What language are you coding in inside of VS?

Comment: T-SQL...Are other flavours of sql allowed ?

Comment: No, I mean your server-side code / "code behind"

Comment: You should create the database in SQL Server, as a server-based database and not fiddle around with attaching `.mdf` files on the fly..... then you just connect to the database server, select the database to use by its logical name, and write queries against tables by their name

Comment: @marc_s ahhh but it is just a local database. I don't have a server.

Comment: If you're using an `.mdf` file, you **do have** SQL Server (Express) installed ....

Comment: yes. But i know only how to attach sql server database in vs. What other software do i need ?

Comment: If you're using VS 2012 with the SQL Server Data Tools - that's all you'll ever need!

Comment: Ok. So it means first i should create a separate database project in vs and then connect it with the project which needs data access right ?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would recommend to go - let the SQL Server Data Tools create the database directly on the server, use the logical database name, and forget about messing around with local `.mdf` files...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of the database.

```
USE master; GO ALTER DATABASE [C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\SQL_PRACTICE\SQL_PRACTICE\ADVENTUREWORKS2012_DATA]  Modify Name = NewDatabaseName; GO
```